# Unable to send email using PHP Sendmail. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method

Tags: php

Unable to send email using PHP Sendmail. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

// config content

```
$protocol = 'sendmail';
$mailpath = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$charset = 'iso-8859-1';
$wordwrap = TRUE;
$mailtype= "html";
$smtp_host= "mail.domain.com";//pengaturan smtp
$smtp_port= "465";
$smtp_timeout= "25";
$user = "";
$pass = "";
```

// config array

```
$config                   = array();
$config['protocol']       = $protocol;
$config['mailpath']       = $mailpath;
$config['charset']        = $charset;
$config['wordwrap']       = $wordwrap;
$config['mailtype']       = $mailtype;
$config['smtp_host']      = $smtp_host;
$config['smtp_port']      = $smtp_port;
$config['smtp_timeout']   = $smtp_timeout;
$config['smtp_user']      = $user;
$config['smtp_pass']      = $pass;
$config['crlf']           = "\r\n";
$config['newline']        = "\r\n";
$config['send_multipart'] = FALSE;
```

// send

```
$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->from($config['smtp_user'], 'Info');
$this->email->to($query['email']);
$this->email->subject("Reset password berhasil");
$this->email->message("adadad");
if ($this->email->send()) {
    echo "berhasil";
}
```

Comment: Edit your question if you want to add more content or if you want to elaborate.

It seems like your using some sort of class/addon, does `mail()` also not work?

Comment: mail()? where i change my program

Answer (score 0):

Well sendmail allows you to send email using the sendmail program installed on your local server. Do you have sendmail installed on your server.

Also you have specified SMTP connection settings in your config file. Maybe you dont need sendmail. Try to change the protocol field from sendmail to smtp.

Comment: i try protocol smtp and is did'nt work, and where i know if sendmail has installed in cpanel

Comment: See contents of php.ini file. It should show if sendmail is installed or not. You can see contents of php.ini file from cpanel or by creating a php file which calls phpinfo(). function. Which php script are you using for sending email?